# How can I make a column editable only to a few users in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a couple of columns in a doc library, which should be editable only for a few users. These users can be part of a single group. However currently, this is editable by all users and does not serve my purpose. 
My SP site is created using WSS 3.0 and workflows are built using SP designer.

Comment: SharePoint out-of-the-box does not support field level permissions...

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting [codeplex project (SPListDisplaySetting)](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/) which will fit your needs, I think?!